# Get the count of rows from a COPY command

Tags: postgresql, count, plpgsql, sqlbulkcopy

When copying data from a file, you get the count of rows in psql with the "command tag":

```
db=# COPY t FROM '/var/lib/postgres/test.sql';
COPY 10
```

I need the number of rows and would like to avoid a redundant `count()` on the table.

Is there a way to get this count from `COPY` directly in a PL/pgSQL function?
As far as I know there is none, but maybe I am missing something?

For PostgreSQL 9.2. But any option in any version would be of interest.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Not in PG 9.2, but there is in PG 9.3 courtesy of Pavel (E 1.3.1.7):

> Allow PL/pgSQL to access the number of rows processed by COPY (Pavel Stehule)
>
> The command is GET DIAGNOSTICS x = ROW_COUNT.

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/devel/static/release-9-3.html

Comment: Right on target, Sir! And kudos to Pavel!