# How do I find out the number of rows copied?

Tags: ruby, postgresql, pg, rowcount, postgresql-copy

I am running a Postgres DB and using the `COPY` command in ruby to load data into a temporary table.

It looks something like this:

```
@conn = PG.connect(dbname: 'load_test')
res = @conn.async_exec <<-QUERY
  COPY tmp_inventory FROM '#{infile_location}' CSV HEADER DELIMITER '|'
QUERY
```

There is an INFO log message with the total number of rows added. How could I get this number programmatically from within ruby?

Comment: @Erwin Brandstetter: Could you help me understand how I would do this in a Ruby context? The linked question is in reference to a query on the PG CLI if I understand correctly.

Comment: I see. Doing it in a Ruby context requires a different approach.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this inside Postgres or get it from the Postgres interface in Ruby directly:

#### Using Ruby

More specifically the class [**`PGresult`**](http://deveiate.org/code/pg/PGresult.html).

I am not a Ruby expert, but studying the documentation [here](http://ruby-doc.org/gems/docs/p/postgres-pr-opt-0.6.9/PGresult.html) and [here](http://deveiate.org/code/pg/PGresult.html), it seems the method `cmd_tuples` only works for `INSERT|DELETE|UPDATE|MOVE|FETCH`.

There are also the constants `PGRES_COPY_OUT` or **`PGRES_COPY_IN`** (for the case at hand). It seems [the method **`result_status`** returns the respective value](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/ged/ruby-pg/PGresult):

> Returns the status of the query. The status value is one of:
>
> ```
> PGRES_EMPTY_QUERY
> PGRES_COMMAND_OK
> PGRES_TUPLES_OK
> PGRES_COPY_OUT
> PGRES_COPY_IN
> PGRES_BAD_RESPONSE
> PGRES_NONFATAL_ERROR
> PGRES_FATAL_ERROR
> PGRES_COPY_BOTH
> ```

So, in your example you should get the desired value with:

```
res.result_status
```

#### Using Postgres

You would use a PL/pgSQL function to access the number of rows processed by `COPY` programmatically (version 9.2+ required):

- [Get the count of rows from a COPY command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16610449/get-the-count-of-rows-from-a-copy-command)

Answer (score 1):

Erwin Brandstetter was on the right track. Despite what the Ruby API documentation currently says (it needs updating), `PG::Result#cmd_tuples` does work with `COPY` commands, at least as of PostgreSQL 9.6.3. It probably didn't when the question was asked, but [the `libpq` documentation for PQcmdTuples](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/libpq-exec.html#LIBPQ-PQCMDTUPLES) now includes `COPY`, so I'll update the Ruby API's docs to reflect that.

This is a modified version of [one of the examples in the source's `sample/` directory](https://bitbucket.org/ged/ruby-pg/src/default/sample/copyfrom.rb?fileviewer=file-view-default) that illustrates this using the `PG::Connection#copy_data` wrapper method around `libpq`'s `COPY` API:

```
require 'pg'
require 'stringio'

$stderr.puts "Opening database connection ..."
conn = PG.connect( dbname: 'test' )

conn.exec( <<END_SQL )
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS logs;
CREATE TABLE logs (
    client_ip inet,
    username text,
    ts timestamp,
    request text,
    status smallint,
    bytes int
);
END_SQL

csv_io = StringIO.new( <<"END_DATA" )
"127.0.0.1","","30/Aug/2010:08:21:24 -0700","GET /manual/ HTTP/1.1",404,205
"127.0.0.1","","30/Aug/2010:08:21:24 -0700","GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1",404,209
"127.0.0.1","","30/Aug/2010:08:21:24 -0700","GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1",404,209
"127.0.0.1","","30/Aug/2010:08:22:29 -0700","GET /manual/ HTTP/1.1",200,11094
"127.0.0.1","","30/Aug/2010:08:22:38 -0700","GET /manual/index.html HTTP/1.1",200,725
"127.0.0.1","","30/Aug/2010:08:27:56 -0700","GET /manual/ HTTP/1.1",200,11094
"127.0.0.1","","30/Aug/2010:08:27:57 -0700","GET /manual/ HTTP/1.1",200,11094
"127.0.0.1","","30/Aug/2010:08:28:06 -0700","GET /manual/index.html HTTP/1.1",200,7709
"127.0.0.1","","30/Aug/2010:08:28:06 -0700","GET /manual/images/feather.gif HTTP/1.1",200,6471
"127.0.0.1","","30/Aug/2010:08:28:06 -0700","GET /manual/images/left.gif HTTP/1.1",200,60
"127.0.0.1","","30/Aug/2010:08:28:06 -0700","GET /manual/style/css/manual.css HTTP/1.1",200,18674
"127.0.0.1","","30/Aug/2010:08:28:06 -0700","GET /manual/style/css/manual-print.css HTTP/1.1",200,13200
"127.0.0.1","","30/Aug/2010:08:28:06 -0700","GET /manual/images/favicon.ico HTTP/1.1",200,1078
"127.0.0.1","","30/Aug/2010:08:28:06 -0700","GET /manual/style/css/manual-loose-100pc.css HTTP/1.1",200,3065
"127.0.0.1","","30/Aug/2010:08:28:14 -0700","OPTIONS * HTTP/1.0",200,0
"127.0.0.1","","30/Aug/2010:08:28:15 -0700","OPTIONS * HTTP/1.0",200,0
"127.0.0.1","","30/Aug/2010:08:28:47 -0700","GET /manual/mod/directives.html HTTP/1.1",200,33561
"127.0.0.1","","30/Aug/2010:08:28:53 -0700","GET /manual/mod/mpm_common.html HTTP/1.1",200,67683
"127.0.0.1","","30/Aug/2010:08:28:53 -0700","GET /manual/images/down.gif HTTP/1.1",200,56
"127.0.0.1","","30/Aug/2010:08:28:53 -0700","GET /manual/images/up.gif HTTP/1.1",200,57
"127.0.0.1","","30/Aug/2010:09:19:58 -0700","GET /manual/mod/mod_log_config.html HTTP/1.1",200,28307
"127.0.0.1","","30/Aug/2010:09:20:19 -0700","GET /manual/mod/core.html HTTP/1.1",200,194144
"127.0.0.1","","30/Aug/2010:16:02:56 -0700","GET /manual/ HTTP/1.1",200,11094
"127.0.0.1","","30/Aug/2010:16:03:00 -0700","GET /manual/ HTTP/1.1",200,11094
"127.0.0.1","","30/Aug/2010:16:06:16 -0700","GET /manual/mod/mod_dir.html HTTP/1.1",200,10583
"127.0.0.1","","30/Aug/2010:16:06:44 -0700","GET /manual/ HTTP/1.1",200,7709
END_DATA

### You can test the error case from the database side easily by
### changing one of the numbers at the end of one of the above rows to
### something non-numeric like "-".

$stderr.puts "Running COPY command with data ..."
buf = ''
conn.transaction do
    res = conn.copy_data( "COPY logs FROM STDIN WITH csv" ) do
        $stderr.print "Sending lines... "
        csv_io.each_line.with_index do |buf, i|
            $stderr.print "#{i + 1} "
            conn.put_copy_data( buf )
        end
        $stderr.puts "done."
    end
    $stderr.puts "Result of COPY is: %s" % [ res.res_status(res.result_status) ]
    $stderr.puts "  tuples copied: %p" % [ res.cmd_tuples ]
end

conn.finish
```

When it's run it outputs:

```
$ ruby sample/copyfrom.rb
Opening database connection ...
Running COPY command with data ...
Sending lines... 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 done.
Result of COPY is: PGRES_COMMAND_OK
  tuples copied: 26
```

The `PG::Result#result_status` method just returns an integer result status code, and `PGRES_COPY_OUT`/`PGRES_COPY_IN` are used by the low level `COPY` API so they're not very useful in the normal case.