# Count rows in massive .csv file

Tags: postgresql, csv, rowcount

dumping a Postgres table out by sections is yielding sections that are 30GB+ in size. The files are landing on a windows 2008 server.  I'm trying to count the rows in the csv to ensure I have a row count that I expect (22,725,303 to be exact).  I can count the rows in the section that I expect to dump - but I am not sure if I'm getting them all.

It's a 190M row table so sections of table is the way to go.

so how can I count the rows so I know I've got the full section?

Comment: Copy the .csv file(s) to a unix machine and run `wc -l thefile.csv` on them?

Comment: Yeah, I'm not keen to move 300GB around the network.  That's onerous.

Comment: Maybe cygwin contains the file-utilities? [alternatively, you could boot from an ubuntu-usb-stick, attempt to mount your(ntfs?) disk, and run `wc -l`] ... Or you could write a small program that just counts the `'\n'` s.

Answer (score 0):

In a PL/pgSQL function, you can get the count of rows processed by the last command - since Postgres 9.3 including `COPY` - with:

```
GET DIAGNOSTICS x = ROW_COUNT;
```

- [Get the count of rows from a COPY command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16610449/get-the-count-of-rows-from-a-copy-command)

Comment: Good call - sadly, Greenplum which is based on Postgres 8.3 might not do this.  I'll give it a go.

Comment: @MatthewCoblentz: You might have mentioned in the *question* that it's about Greenplum, which is *not* Postgres by a long shot. I doubt my answer works for Greenplum.